# Last scene in Django Unchained where Django & Shultz are practicing in the snow?

Tags: analysis, plot-explanation, django-unchained

During the last scene of Django Unchained, when Django and Broomhilda are on their horses, after Django has destroyed everything, we suddenly see a scene where Django and Dr. Schultz are somewhere in the snow. Django is practicing shooting and Shultz tells him *"You know what they are going to call you? The Gun of the South."*
After that Django and Broomhilda take off.

I found it a little unusual.
Is there anything that the director wanted to tell through that scene at the end.
What was the significance of this scene?

Comment: To me that part just screamed "Were putting this here incase we want a sequel"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't catch any reference to future sequels — also because sequels are not decided by open endings or similar stuff, they are decided by the money the film managed to make and the likelihood of a sequel having a similar success (and revenue) —, rather a reference and play on the popular and fixed expression *fastest gun in the west*.

I can't find an official script to quote from but I guess he does mention the "fastest/quickest" part too.

Now, considering most Western movies are set in... the Western part of the North American continent (with exceptions, some of which quite notable), I think that here what Tarantino was trying to convey was the fact that Django was among the best, if not the best, man with a gun in the South.

This is the only explanation I can think of and I couldn't see anything else on the internet that would suggest otherwise.

Comment: I also remeber *Tarantino* having called the movie a *"Southern"* (in analogy to *Western*) in some interview, which would be pretty in line with your answer.

Comment: @ChristianRau Now that you mention it, I think I have heard that too somewhere. :)

Answer (score 1):

"The Fastest Gun In The South" line raises the hairs on my arms every time.
I think three of the answers are practical;

1) "The Fastest Gun In The South" - 1) A PERFECT title for the film sequel if it ever came to be; 
2) It is summation of the man Django became-
a person with the sand and ability to fight Slavery's injustice.

Obviously the intention of this line at the end-placed out of chronology- sums up Django's memory of Dr. Schultz--the refinement of Django's gift, the mutual respect between the two, but most importantly---King sees a legend in the making-- A man of a suffering people with ability to become a hero for all time by freeing his people.

2) The fastest gun in the West could not exist until the movement West. Django is set a few decades before that culture came to be---the moniker "The Fastest Gun In The South" suggests before the white man tamed the West by a mix of genocide, lies, and genuine hard work--then created the white hat hero Cowboy image to erase the real history--
 The fact that a black man rose up to rescue many from one of the worst evils man has ever unleashed---legal slavery---with the tools one associates with the cowboy myth---is a noble, clever, and downright socially revelant reinvention of the Cowboy .

Answer (score -1):

I agree with RhysW - they may have planned for a sequel.

Another reason is that this movie is from the Slave period and... you will understand in a moment that why I have mentioned this.

We have heard this phrase "Fastest Gun in...." in a lot of cartoons and movies but none have seemed to be from such old times.

Thus the directors may be trying to convey that this phrase has come from DJANGO.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this wasn't just included as an option for a sequel (a deduction I can't even follow) and neither does your last sentence sound like a reasonable motivation or deduction.